# Sort a file according to values in first column

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, sorting

I have a file containing results (integers) in several columns (tab separated), two lines of text at the beginning telling me something about the file's contents and two lines at the end telling me if the file's contents are complete.

I have a script to order the file according to the value of the first column but would like to extend it so it skips the first two, and last two lines of the file while also only printing out the ordered first column. How could I do so?

This is the script that I currently have:

```
file_name = "output1.dat"

new_file_name = "sorted_"+file_name
data = csv.reader(open(file_name),delimiter='\t')
sortedlist = sorted(data, key=lambda x:int(x[0]))
#now write the sorte result into new CSV file
with open(new_file_name, "wb") as f:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in sortedlist:
        fileWriter.writerow(row)
```

It gets tripped up by the lines of text as they don't contain any columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should skip first two and last two lines:

```
sortedlist = sorted(list(data)[2:-2], key=lambda x:int(x[0]))
```

Write only the first column:

```
fileWriter.writerow(row[:1])
```

Full script:

```
file_name = "output1.dat"

new_file_name = "sorted_"+file_name
data = csv.reader(open(file_name),delimiter='\t')
sortedlist = sorted(list(data)[2:-2], key=lambda x:int(x[0]))
#now write the sorte result into new CSV file
with open(new_file_name, "wb") as f:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in sortedlist:
        fileWriter.writerow(row[:1])
```